# problem when implementing a selection listener in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing a JTable with different rows. I would like to associate an event to the selection of a row in this table. I have used the following selection class to provide behaviour to the table selection:

```
public class TableSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener{

public Integer item;    

public TableSelectionListener(Integer item){
    this.dialog = item;
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    System.out.println("The row clicked is "+item);

    }
}
```

When I create an instance of this table, sai *tabletest*, I have added the following piece of code:

```
tabletest.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new TableSelectionListener(tabletest.getSelectedRow());
```

The problem is that when I click on one row once, instead of retrieving the related message once, I retrieve the same message several times, suggesting that the actions repeated several times. For example:

```
The row clicked is 0
The row clicked is 0
The row clicked is 0
The row clicked is 0
```

Does anyone know where the problem may be?

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's just normal.

Your selection listener is created with the value of `tabletest.getSelectedRow()` at its creation table (which is zero). And, as you never change the value of `item` in your listener, this listener fcan only display `0`as a result.

If I were you, I wouold replace the `valueChanged()` method by something like (although it's untested and I remember strange things happens sometimes when mixing view and model row values) this :

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) // added as sometimes, multiple events are fired while selection changes
        System.out.println("The row clicked is "+e.getFirstIndex());
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work: if I click the second and third row the message output is correct: "The row clicked is 1" and "The row clicked is 2". However when I click the first row instead of giving me 0 it gives me again 2.

Comment: Alternative approach would be to ask in the listener from the table what rows have been selected.

Comment: `e.getFirstIndex()` isn't very reliable. use table.getSelectedRow() - it's more stable.

Comment: Late addition. The selection model "remembers" the lowest and highest row selected. It needs this information for shift-click situations, where all the rows between are selected. The method names are a warning.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it's perfectly normal to get multiple `ListSelectionEvent`s, while the selection is being changed. You can use the [`getValueIsAdjusting`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting%28%29) method to determine when selection has ended (it will return `false`).

Secondly, there's no need to construct your `TableSelectionListener` with a row number. When your `valueChanged` method is called, you can get the index of the first/last selected row (remember it's possibly to select multiple rows in the table, unless you disable that) using `e.getFirstIndex()` and `e.getLastIndex()` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way of doing it, is as follows:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("e...."+table.getSelectedRow());
    }
});
```

Comment: the price you pay for this felt simplicity is coupling from the listener to the table - typically not what you want. Also, you forgot the check for isAdjusting: typically, you want to ignore such events.